# Javascript - Video auto play issue

Tags: javascript, video, autoplay

I'm working on a script that make a video autoplay. I tried but it didn't work. I have attached my code and my test link below for more clarification.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",  videoPlay);

function videoPlay(){
    var scrollTop     = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var  elementOffset =  jQuery("#my_video_1").offset().top;
    distance      = ( elementOffset - scrollTop );

    if(distance <= 250){
        let player = document.querySelector("#my_video_1");
        player.muted= true;
        player.play();
        // return player
    }
}
```

http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/test-coder/contact.html

Please help on this. Thanks:)

Comment: What I want is when we reach on that video section by scrolling the video should play automatically.

Comment: `<style>` is not a valid child of `<html>`

Comment: `TypeError: player.play is not a function`

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for your response..I'm removing style from html and will update the link.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",  videoPlay);

     function videoPlay(){
            var scrollTop     = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            var  elementOffset =  jQuery("#my_video_1").offset().top;
            distance      = ( elementOffset - scrollTop );

            if(distance <= 250){
                var myPlayer = videojs('my_video_1');
                myPlayer.play();
                jQuery("#my_video_1").addClass("vjs-playing");
               }
            }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185573/discussion-on-answer-by-harshit-tailor-javascript-video-auto-play-issue).